# Can I disable completion filtering in Ace Editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6MVntVmXYUbjR0DI82Cr?p=preview) uses a rhyming dictionary to do autocompletion.

```
var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setOptions({enableBasicAutocompletion: true});
// uses http://rhymebrain.com/api.html
var rhymeCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        if (prefix.length === 0) { callback(null, []); return }
        $.getJSON(
            "http://rhymebrain.com/talk?function=getRhymes&word=" + prefix,
            function(wordList) {
                // wordList like [{"word":"flow","freq":24,"score":300,"flags":"bc","syllables":"1"}]
                callback(null, wordList.map(function(ea) {
                    return {name: ea.word, value: ea.word, score: ea.score, meta: "rhyme"}
                }));
            })
    }
}
langTools.addCompleter(rhymeCompleter);
```

For example, type "trace" and hit ctrl-space, and only a few suggestions pop up (retrace, interlace, interface).

The rhyming dictionary actually suggested many other matches, and they were passed in to the callback, but internally Ace filtered them out because they don't contain the letters "t", "r", "a", "c", and "e". Is there a way to bypass that filter so that it suggests all of the things that were passed to the callback?

Answer (score 1):

The Autocompletion is filtered by ace in the autocompleter file. But you can set insertMatch to avoid this filter,

```
insertMatch: function(editor, data) {
    editor.completer.insertMatch({value: data.value})
});
```

You can update the callback function in this way:

```
callback(null,
  wordList.map(function (word) {
             return {
                caption: word,
                value: word,
                    completer: {
                        insertMatch: function (editor, data) {
                            editor.completer.insertMatch({value: data.value})
                        }
                   }
   }
```

Comment: insertMatch is called after the user clicks on the option, but it doesn't seem to be invoked until after the list is filtered. Am I missing something? (I implemented your suggestion at http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNQNrVcrBv88gaeCPGlG